# What is the point of signal amplification if noise is also amplified?

Tags: amplifier

Sorry for my ignorance but there's is immense effort in electrical engineering in the topic of amplification. I can understand the reason for circuits rejecting noise or filtering noise, but have difficulty to grasp the reason behind signal amplification such as a single ended input output amplifier.

If signal is amplified the noise is also amplified so SNR will remain the same. SNR might even be worse because of the amplifying active circuit will introduce extra noise.

Can you give me a reason to amplify let's say a 0-50mV noisy signal to 0-3.3V range by a single ended amplifier which is coupled to a 0-3.3V 12-bit ADC? Or another example that makes the linear amplification important`.

**EDIT UPDATE:**

After reading the answers especially Spehro Pefhany's answer and the comments sections, I tried to quantify the estimate SNRs for both cases. I ignored external interference or ADC inherent thermal noise, I also ignored amplifier noise. I only used the 1mV rms signal noise and the uncorrelated ADC quantization error for calculations.

Please see the following equations in the Python code and let me know if there's any mistake:

```
import numpy as np;

ADC_range = 3.3
ADC_resolution  = 12
ADC_quant_error = ADC_range / (2**ADC_resolution -1)

# Without amplification
V_input_sig_range = 0.05
V_input_sig_range_rms = 0.05 / np.sqrt(2)
V_noise_rms = 0.001
V_total_rms_noise = np.sqrt(V_noise_rms**2 + ADC_quant_error**2)
SNR = 20 * np.log10(V_input_sig_range_rms / V_total_rms_noise)

# With amplification
V_input_sig_range_amplified = 3.3
V_input_sig_range_amplified_rms = 3.3 / np.sqrt(2)
V_noise_rms_amplified = 0.066
V_total_rms_noise_amplified = np.sqrt(V_noise_rms_amplified**2 + ADC_quant_error**2)
SNR_amplified = 20 * np.log10(V_input_sig_range_amplified_rms / V_total_rms_noise_amplified)

print(SNR)
print(SNR_amplified)
```

The above results as:

SNR = 28.795 dB

SNR_amplified = 30.968 dB

The difference is 2.17 dB

Comment: Hard to seperate noise from the signal when at 50mV.  Amplify everything and now noise can be filtered.

Comment: oh good point. you mean the amplifier will provide a low output impedance buffer so we can filter correctly??? but then its not the amplification but buffering does the job here.

Comment: Often you can't do anything the signal at all because it's so small until amplified. If you amplify the signal and the noise by the same amount, now you can do other stuff with it. You seem to be assuming all low amplitude signals have low SNR, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Also look into lock-in amplifiers.

Comment: imagine a filter stage that adds 10 mV noise ... feed in 50 mV signal and get 50 mV signal out, with added 10 mV noise ... now think about the noise in the output of the following, amplify the 50 mV signal to 1 V, feed it into the same filter, and then attenuate the output down to 50 mV

Comment: Isn't the point that however much noise goes with it, an insignificant signal can always be amplified?

What matters is whether the SNR is overwhelming. How could that not depend on the circumstances of each particular case?

Whether your resources make that worth doing is a different thing. Whether in your case it's even worth doing a cost-benefit analysis is another different thing.

Comment: please have a look at my edit in question. let me know if something is wrong

Comment: That looks correct. The improvement is not so great because you have so very low SNR to begin with. If you assume noise of 100uV rather than 1mV you'd have more like a 19dB improvement.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Exactly that made a huge difference. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: It's often because you're going to send the signal through another channel *after* you amplify it. You can't do anything about noise that's in the signal already, but amplifying will decrease the signal-to-noise ratio for any noise that gets added after the amplification.

Comment: Repeating Virgo, the point is amplify the thing ***before*** the noise is added.  But not too much that makes yer circuits go nonlinear.

Comment: I wonder if it would make sense to clarify what kinds of signals you're asking about. The ultimate point of audio signal amplification is to be able drive some kind of speaker. SNR is meaningless if the sound is completely inaudible. And obviously it's possible to design high gain audio circuits that also result in audio with favorable SNR (>60 dB).

Comment: This might be relevant https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_formulas_for_noise, basically you amplify to compensate for the fact that later stages might add lots of noise, in the case of RF its usually the mixer

Comment: Most RF receivers will have a thing called a "low noise amplifier" right next to the antenna. The idea is to amplify the signal *as soon as possible* (before more noise is added), and add as little noise as possible while doing this amplification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of the ADC you should consider the noise the ADC adds.

If it's an ideal 12-bit converter and you are using 0-50mV out of 0-3.3V full scale you effectively have a 6-bit converter (5.95 bits). The quantization noise (even for an ideal converter) is quite large. Reality will be worse than this.

Comment: Imagine the noise is 1mV. In 0-50mV case I have 50 effective steps. And if I amplify the signal will be 0-3.3V but the noise will be 66mV. 3300/66 = 50 steps. So in both case I have 50 steps representation of the signal. Im sorry but Im stuck here.

Comment: @user4444 You would have 3300-66=3234 quantization steps. This quantization error will be much smaller.

Comment: @user4444 Besides quantization noise, often an ADC will require driving by a low impedance source to obtain its theoretical performance. So for example you might take a 3.3v 12 bit ADC and try to drive it with a high impedance source producing 50mV and get no signal out at all if the source cannot drive the ADC. In this case an amplifier will enable you to obtain the expected 50:1 SNR.

Comment: In both cases ADC is the same 12-bit ADC how come you two are talking about different quantization noise? SNR = 6.02N + 1.76dB and N is same in both cases.

Comment: @user4444 Also "imagine the noise is 1mV" is nonsensical.  Noise is a statistic signal.  It has correlations, and your signal has statistics and significant bandwidth.  If you take more than a single measurement, you get a time series.  And depending on the bandwidth you are trying to interpret, you can process the signal and make predictions and probabilities about its actual values (check out, for example, Wiener filtering).  For that you need to have measured its noise-affected version with sufficient resolution.

Comment: rms of the noise

Comment: @user4444 N is not the same in both cases. In the former it is less than 5, in the latter it is 12.

Comment: okay maybe Im missing some math here. I think I dont get why ADC quant noise is different. Can you provide me a formula for both cases?

Comment: I would like to see the difference in overall resolution both cases and see if there's a need for amplification?

Comment: @user4444 The ADC 's quantization error is unchanged, but since the signal is 66 times larger, the quantization noise limited SNR is 66 times larger. In your equation (for SNR not quantization error), you must count only levels used to quantize the signal, which is about 6 bits. The next 6 bits are always zero and thus unused. Probably many questions on this math here and on the DSP stack exchange if you would like to learn more.

Comment: In both cases the overall quantization is around 6-bits (66 steps) Spehro Pefhany answer doesnt account for 1mV noise.

Comment: @user4444 Did you miss above where I explained why that's wrong? If you're confused, explain what you don't understand.

Comment: @user1850479 You didnt explain you told me to ask in signal processing stackechange . In both cases the overall quantization is around 6-bits (66 steps) Spehro Pefhany answer doesnt account for 1mV noise.  Do u have an answer for this? If so answer by using formulas and math. That would be an answer. Look also SteveSh's answer doesnt agree with you as well.

Comment: @user4444 To reiterate, amplifying the signal has no effect on quantization error, which is always 3.3v/4096. Amplifying the signal by 66 makes the signal 66 times larger. The ratio of signal to quantization noise added thus increases by 66 times.. Thus, the effect of quantization error is 66 times smaller. Does that make sense to you? SteveSh's answer does not mention quantization error, so it's unclear in what sense you think it disagrees.

Comment: The original signal-to-noise ratio will not be changed (or be made slightly worse) by analog amplification to match the ADC's full scale. The additional quant noise will however be minimized; the signal-to-quantization noise ratio is ≈ 6.02•Q dB where Q is the number of quantization bits.  Amplifying the signal allows the use of more quantization bits.

Comment: Your hypothetical 1mV-noise- fundamentally the noises all add, if they are not correlated they add in **quadrature** (square root of sum of squares) at **best**.  So reducing ADC quantization noise by a factor of 66 (referred to the input) reduces the system noise, perhaps by a lot, perhaps only by a little if your signal is hardly worthy of a 12-bit ADC. Similarly, ADC drift (effectively low frequency noise) can be reduced by a similar factor if your amplifier does not add significant drift.

Comment: @vir Regarding your: "The additional quant noise will however be minimized; the signal-to-quantization noise ratio is ≈ 6.02•Q dB where Q is the number of quantization bit"     Isnt Q always 12 for the 12-bit ADC regardless of the input signal range? I dont get that part. How come the input signal range has effect to quantization level of the ADC or quantization noise? Cannot find any info about it or a detailed "formula". Please a formula(equation) which shows this relation you talk about.

Comment: Q is not 12 because the signal range is not equal to the full scale of the ADC input. A 12-bit ADC with 3.3V full scale is ≈0.8mV per step (3.3/4096). A 50mV signal would only use 62.5 steps (50/0.8), which can be represented with 6 bits (2^6).  The rest are all zero and remain zero. Amplifying the input to match the full scale range uses all 12 bits and doubles your signal-to-quant-noise ratio [(6.02 • 12) / (6.02 • 6)]

Comment: I see I think you mean the ADC quantization error remains the same in volts(for both cases). But becomes smaller as a fraction of the signal's voltage swing. If there was no quantization error, in both cases with 1mV noise the overall SNR would be same and around 20log(50/1) or 20log(3300/66) = 34dB. How can we plug in your quantization formulas to these 34dB SNRs so that we can see how much two cases differ in overall SNR(in dB)? Thanks

Comment: Hi please have a look at my update in question. I followed the dissuasions here and came up with some dB to compare two cases. Let me know if theres something wrong.

Answer (score 41):

Preamplification is an engineer's cavalry.  You put your best forces in the most strategic place so that the infantry can do its job at their skill level.

Low-noise circuitry is expensive and tricky.  The job is not done by just picking specific low-noise opamps: thermal noise is everywhere.  If you throw your expertise and the expensive parts and the high power requirements of low-impedance circuitry into preamplification, the further processing has lots more leeway to admit more noise: those additional noise levels will then be dwarved by the amplified signal noise.

Without preamplification, the *whole* processing chain has to be ultra-low-noise rather than just the first stage.  That's much more difficult and ultimately more expensive.

Comment: This is what immediately came to mind when reading the question. And here I find it down a ways. Oh, well. +1 for a boost. The point of first contact with a transducer matters. Afterwards it is just the usual trade-offs with bandwidth.

Comment: But (and this a key): pre-amplification, any kind of amplification for that matter, does nothing to improve the SNR of the signal coming into the amplifier.  If the incoming signal is noisy, so will be the output of the amplifier.  Something like a well designed microwave LNA just adds the smallest amount of noise to the amplified signal.

Comment: The key point here is that you are anticipating the signal to incur **constant amplitude additive noise** downstream of the pre-amplifier. In this case the effect of the pre-amp is to guard against an anticipated DOWNSTREAM hit to SNR that would occur without the pre-amp.

Comment: A good way to see this in electronic applications is to look at wiring and PCB traces before and after preamplification. Before the amplifier, traces are typically rounded, bordered by stitching vias, are carefully routed away from components that might induce electrical noise and go out to grounded connectors with heavily shielded cables. After, it's pretty much the same as any other analogue signal.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, analog design is kind of a lose-lose.  Everything you do to a signal actually makes it worse (even filtering).

The goal is to make it better in the specific ways that your acquisition circuit needs.

Your ADC for example has a hard job of accurately digitizing a signal and it’s easiest to do on signals with certain properties - full scale voltage on the order of volts, and noise content below the sampling frequency.

Opamps on the other hand don’t mind tiny signals and with careful design your front end can condition a signal for accurate acquisition while losing less than you gain in the end.

Answer (score 9):

There is a very obvious case where application is very useful: when your signal is going to be **transmitted**, whether over wires or wirelessly, where noise will be added during the transmission, so **after** the amplification.

Since the level of noise will not depend on the level of the original signal, your SNR at the other end will be greatly improved over a non-amplified signal.

```
50mV signal -> no amplicification -> transmission adds 50mV noise -> arg.
50mv signal -> amplification to 5V -> transmission adds 50mV noise -> yea!
```

While this is very true for transmission over longer distances, or over media prone to a lot of noise (e.g. wireless), this can be true over relatively short distances as well.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you give me a reason to amplify let's say a 0 - 50 mV noisy signal to 0 - 3.3V range by a single ended amplifier which is coupled to a 0 - 3.3V 12-bit ADC?

Sure: resolution.

A 12-bit ADC will have 4096 steps which, in the case of your 3.3 V ADC, will have a step size or resolution of 800 μV per step and a digital output of 0 to 4095. Ignoring noise that's a resolution of 0.025%.

The 50 mV signal, if unamplified, would only have a maximum of 0.050 / 3.3 × 4096 = 62 counts so the digital range would be 0 to 61. Ignoring noise, that's a resolution of 1.5%.

> Or another example that makes the linear amplification important.

Audio amplification! The headphone output of your phone won't drive a large loudspeaker. An amplifier boosts the signal to a suitable level and power to put enough electrical energy into the speaker to put enough mechanical energy into the air.

> If signal is amplified the noise is also amplified so SNR will remain the same.

And that's fine. If you're listening on headphones or on a large PA system the noise will be the same distance "below" the signal level.

> SNR might even be worse because of the amplifying active circuit will introduce extra noise.

Yes, in general the signal degrades but high quality electronics can do a lot to keep the introduced noise and distortion low.

Comment: But Im taking about noisy signal. You example the signal has no noise. Imagine the noise is 1mV. In 0-50mV case I have 50 effective steps. And if I amplify the signal will be 0-3.3V but the noise will be 66mV. 3300/66 = 50 steps. So in both case I have 50 steps representation of the signal?

Comment: In the 50 step mode your quantization noise makes the S/N ratio much worse. You are applying 50-step quantization to the desired signal as well as the noise.

Comment: Yes but you have less quantization noise and can now reduce the original noise in the digitized signal with DSP techniques after the ADC.

Comment: In both cases ADC is the same 12-bit ADC how come you say different quantization noise? SNR = 6.02N + 1.76dB and N is same in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

The point of amplifying analog 50mV signal to 3.3V to read the value with 12-bit MCU ADC is to use the full scale of the 12-bit range of 0..4096.

If you keep the value at 50mV, you have only range of 0..62 for the digital codes.

If you can work with 62 codes for the whole 50mV signal then that's fine, but 4096 codes for the 50mV signal may be better.

Comment: Imagine the noise is 1mV. In 0-50mV case I have 50 effective steps. And if I amplify the signal will be 0-3.3V but the noise will be 66mV. 3300/66 = 50 steps. So in both case I have 50 steps representation of the signal. Im sorry but Im stuck here.

Comment: No, you're right.  Amplifying a noisy signal does not help with the effective resolution of the ADC.  What it does help with is with any additional noise added to the signal before the ADC,

Comment: @user4444: Consider an ADC with fewer bits, or an even lower input signal level.  In those cases, quantization noise could be more significant than the 1 part in 50 noise level of your input signal.

Answer (score 3):

How noisy is your 0-50 mV signal?  You didn't say, so I'll use a contrived example with some approximations for a back-of-the envelope analysis.

**Case 1 - Apply The Signal+Noise Directly to the ADC**

Your 12-bit ADC has an LSB of about 800 uV.  Your 0-50 mV signal is about 6 bits (62 quanta), the lower 6 bits of this ADC (50 mV/800 uV about 62).

Now if your noise is 10 mV, that will affect/corrupt, 12 quanta of the ADC's output or a bit less than 4 bits.  The information you care about will only be contained in 2 bits.

**Case 2 - Amplify the Signal+Noise, Then Input to the ADC**

Now say you amplify the signal so that your 50 mV, plus noise, signal uses the full range of the ADC.  You would have to amplify that signal, and its noise, by 66.  In this case, the 2 MSB's of the ADC's output would contain the information, and the lower 10 bits would just represent amplified noise.

So in both case you only have 2 bits (or a little more) of information content in the output of the ADC.  The only difference is in which bits that information is contained.

Comment: please have a look at my update in question. let me know if something is wrong

Comment: That looks reasonable, though I am not at all familiar with Python.  The improvement in SNR in the amplified case is due to the reduced effects of quantization noise on the AD'd value.  But that's slightly different from your original question, which had to do with the effects on SNR on amplifying a signal.

Comment: And yes, my contrived example ignored ADC quantization effects.

Comment: You changed reasoning between Case 1  and Case 2. For signal processing, it is very important difference when useful information is in 50=62-12 quanta (Case 1) and when it is in 62*66 - 12*66 = 50*66 = 3300 quanta (Case 2). Underutilization of ADC's FS, just worsening SNR!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to amplify a signal even if the S/N ratio becomes worse afterwards. For example, if your signal is a square wave 0-50mV and you want to drive a TTL circuit you need to amplify it otherwise you won't be able to trigger the input of a TTL chip as it requires much higher threshold input voltage to change its state. If your signal is an audio signal 0-50mV and you want to drive a speaker, then without amplification you won't be able to move the speker's diaphrame enough to produce sufficiently audible signal. If your signal comes from an output of a high impedance source and you want to drive with it a low impedance device you need to use impedance matching amplifier (or another impedance conversion device) to be able to do that. And many other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The amplifiers are used not to improve you SNR but for signal conditioning so you can use this signal on a way you want to use it. At first place, almost never your "load" impedance match your source impedance, and when saying match this no meen is the same, but is suitable for. An example, an ADC input is usually around 10 k , but there are many sources wit similar and impedance, as a result you signal will be attenuated, an in some case this can be also non linear attenuation. Having on mind that the input resistance ma depend on multiple factors, it's virtually impossible to compensate for that.
Another good reason is to match the amplitude/current. If you drive a load that requires high current, or in case wit the ADC have predefined range this must be matched as well. If you have 100 mV pp signal you will never get the full ADC resolution, unless your reference is not 100 mV but that's not the case. To get the maximum from the ADC you want your max signal to be close to your Vref as amplitude.
The amplifiers not only didn't change SNR but since they have theirs own noise they reduce it, but still are required.
p.s
And your calculation is not correct at all. What if you have a 10 bit ADC, 1.2 V reference and 1 mV signal ?

Comment: I'm not following you here *At first place, almost never your "load" impedance match your source impedance, and when saying match this no meen is the same, but is suitable for.* Do you mean "this does not mean it is the same"? And "but is suitable for" - suitable for what?

Comment: 10 bit ADC, 1.2 V reference and 1 mV signal I still get better SNR in amplified case

Comment: With 10 bit ADC, 1 mV signal and 1.2 V reference you will not get a signal at all, simply because the signal is smaller than your ADC LSB. Your ADC is not able to read anything below 1.5/1024 or approx 1.46 mv, and you have a signal with amplitude 1 mV. You won't be able even to detect is there is a signal or not. And this is very optimistic, because with a normal 10 bit ADC, I mean like those in most uC the best you will get is around 8.5 bits, that will render it useless even for a 10 mV signal. So on the digital side you will not have any signal at all, only noise.

Comment: And on the first comment, when you say matched impedances usually that mean exactly that, you have 50 ohm source and 50 ohm load, they are matched. In that case matched =suitable, with other words suitable to be acquired by the ADC. Imagine you have high impedance source let say 100k and a standard uC ADC with impedance around 10 kOm. If simplified this is a voltage divider, you will get 1/11 of the signal. Unfortunately is not so simple and is very hard to say what you will measure. Besides that, your ADC may start bussing the source, that also becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right. If you have an ADC with 0-50 mV input range, there is no need to amplify your 0-50 mV signal. However, you will need amplification if the input of the receiving device needs a larger voltage. Examples are: ADC with 3.3 V input range, a loudspeaker (think of several Watt), or a radio transmitter antenna (think of watts to kilowatts).

Just another detail: impedance. Even if the ADC is 0-50 mV, you will need an amplifier if the input impedance of the ADC is too low. The voltage amplification may be just the factor of one. The 'amplifier' is then called 'buffer'.

Answer (score 0):

> If signal is amplified the noise is also amplified so SNR will remain the same

No, it will not. If a signal is passed through an amplifier with power gain P, then the noise is amplified P times while the signal power is amplified \$P^2\$ times. Overall, the SNR is improved P times. But as you said, the amplifier will also add noise of its own so the improvement will be less than P.

Answer (score 0):

Other than noise considerations, a further good reason to not only pre-amplify but *pre-condition* signals is that it enables good system design. I am going to use the example of an analogue audio mixer here.

The job of such a mixer is to take many audio signals from different sources, and enable them to be manipulated in all kinds of ways and then combined into any number of outputs. On a system level this is pretty complex; standardising on signal levels in the system makes things much easier.

Sources include:

- microphones with all kinds of varying senstitivities and of different types (some need DC phantom power, some don't). Always balanced, levels between about -60 and -10dBu.
- various "line" sources (e.g. playback devices, outputs from musical equipment such as guitar amps or "outboard" effects) which also have quite varied signal levels, between roughly -10 and +10dBu, some balanced, some not.

Within the console, there is a plethora of ways to filter these disparate sources and combine them into various outputs. Within the console, pretty much everything runs on (unbalanced) amp circuits, and generally power rails of +/-17VDC or so. Given that we generally want at LEAST 20dB of headroom to avoid clipping, it is usual to define an "internal operating level" which is typically around 0dBu (more or less).

So in practice we end up with a general purpose preamp which does the following:

- allow line or mic signals to be connected.
- for mic signals, allow switchable phantom power for mics.
- give a range of variable gain to allow external signals to be bought up to the internal operating level.
- give some sort of visible metering to show when signal level is "OK" or "too close to clipping" (at least a green/red LED).
- fery often , other useful features such as a dedicated filter to remove bothersome low frequency compenents ("plosives"), or to reverse the phase of a signal (useful when many mics are used together).
- providing good immunity to RFI or EMC
- giving some frequency tailoring ("DC to light" is NOT desirable), typically a gentle rolloff at 20Hz and 40kHz or so.

It's pretty hard to see how such a system would be usable without these preamps. An internal circuit such as an equaliser would still work at (say) -30dBu but the practical business of mixing would be just unmanageable.

The qualities of low noise and distortion are still very important and highly valued in this environment - but the preamp has a lot of other functions other than that.

Even in a more modern system (say a PC based system where signals are captured through a soundcard and then manipulated digitally) - we STILL care a lot about that preamp. Your internal processing might all be 32 bit floating point - but if you didn't first condition the signal well for the ADC, you are not getting the best results, because you are introducing more conversion noise or artefacts than you need to.

In summary : **preamps are there to interface, amplify and condition external signals so that the system can be designed to work under known, controlled conditions.**